# Delphi, Editor for Button, preserve default click in IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, toolsapi

XE3 Prof, Win64.

I created a new Button component, based on TButton.

It have a special menu in IDE, named "Set Button Style".

```
procedure Register;
begin
    RegisterComponents('SComps', [TSAButton]);
    RegisterComponentEditor(TSAButton, TSAButtonEditor);
end;

procedure TSAButtonEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
begin
    Set_Style(TSAButton(Component));
end;

function TSAButtonEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): string;
begin
    Result := 'Set Button Style';
end;

function TSAButtonEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
begin
    Result := 1;
end;
```

The button's have special click in IDE - the double click on the component generates OnClick in my code.

After I installed my editor menu, this capability lost, because IDE calls my function, and not the original (the default code generating).

How can I restore this capability in my button with preserving my menu too?

Thanks for every info!

dd

Comment: Specific Delphi version should be in your tags. Since you already have 5 tags, you'll have to remove the least relevant one to add `delphi-xe3`

Comment: I don't understand what this means: *After I installed my editor menu, this capability lost, because IDE calls my function, and not the original.*

Comment: When you click on normal button, your IDE generates you "onclick" to dfm/pas. After I installed my editor, IDE calls my "Set Button Style" function. So the "onclick" generate lost for me.

Comment: Detect if you are running in the IDE and call the original OnClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your Editor was inherited from TComponentEditor ?
if So , you need to call the default Edit function in order to generates OnClick event of your component inside your editor ExecuteVerb function .
Note : the Edit function is empty in the TComponentEditor class ..
So you need to use the IDefaultEditor interface to call the Edit function :

First Method :

```
procedure TYourEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
var
  DefEditor: IDefaultEditor;
begin
  DefEditor := TDefaultEditor.Create(Component, Designer);
  DefEditor.Edit;
  case Index of
    0:
      // DoSomething !!
      // ...
      // ...
    end;
      //...
end;
```

Second Method :

You have another way : You can inherite your Editor from TDefaultEditor class (and not from TComponentEditor) :

```
 TYourEditor = class(TDefaultEditor)
  .....
procedure TYourEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

But if you use the second method , you will lose your capability (Only when double click, other context menu will apear normaly ).
i would prefer using the first method .

Comment: I tried to do your first solution. The first version was wrong, because onclick and my menu also shown. Next I put two menus: 0.) OnClick 1.) Set Style Dialog, and I called Edit only in case 0. It's cool, working. But: need I to Free the DefEditor on the end of the procedure? I'm not sure now...

Comment: @durumdara : No you don't need to free `DefEditor` , its an interface , and it will be destroyed automatically .